# Highchart with date range

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I use highchart with react js, in the X axis I have dates in days, when the period is very long the x axis becomes with points and the display does not work, is there a possibility that highchart manages this case when I give it the dates it displays them on the x axis it escapes dates between them[image]

My options

```
  const options = {
        chart: {
            type: "line",
        },
        title: {
            text: "",
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: "",
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories:[
    "2022-09-21",
    "2022-09-22",
    "2022-09-23",
    "2022-09-24",
    "2022-09-25",
    "2022-09-26",
    "2022-09-27",
    "2022-09-28",
    "2022-09-29",
    "2022-09-30",
    "2022-10-01",
    "2022-10-02",
    "2022-10-03",
    "2022-10-04",
    "2022-10-05",
    "2022-10-06",
    "2022-10-07",
    "2022-10-08",
    "2022-10-09",
    "2022-10-10",
    "2022-10-11",
    "2022-10-12",
    "2022-10-13",
    "2022-10-14",
    "2022-10-15",
    "2022-10-16",
    "2022-10-17",
    "2022-10-18",
    "2022-10-19",
    "2022-10-20",
    "2022-10-21",
    "2022-10-22",
    "2022-10-23",
    "2022-10-24",
    "2022-10-25",
    "2022-10-26",
    "2022-10-27",
    "2022-10-28",
    "2022-10-29",
    "2022-10-30",
    "2022-10-31",
    "2022-11-01",
    "2022-11-02",
    "2022-11-03",
    "2022-11-04",
    "2022-11-05",
    "2022-11-06",
    "2022-11-07",
    "2022-11-08",
    "2022-11-09",
    "2022-11-10",
    "2022-11-11",
    "2022-11-12",
    "2022-11-13",
    "2022-11-14",
    "2022-11-15",
    "2022-11-16",
    "2022-11-17",
    "2022-11-18",
    "2022-11-19",
    "2022-11-20",
    "2022-11-21",
    "2022-11-22",
    "2022-11-23",
    "2022-11-24",
    "2022-11-25",
    "2022-11-26",
    "2022-11-27",
    "2022-11-28",
    "2022-11-29",
    "2022-11-30",
    "2022-12-01",
    "2022-12-02",
    "2022-12-03",
    "2022-12-04",
    "2022-12-05",
    "2022-12-06",
    "2022-12-07",
    "2022-12-08",
    "2022-12-09",
    "2022-12-10",
    "2022-12-11",
    "2022-12-12",
    "2022-12-13",
    "2022-12-14",
    "2022-12-15",
    "2022-12-16",
    "2022-12-17",
    "2022-12-18",
    "2022-12-19",
    "2022-12-20",
    "2022-12-21"
],
            crosshair: true,
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: "",
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat:
                '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat:
                '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}%</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: "</table>",
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0,
            },
        },
        series: [
            {
                name: “Data”,
                data: [
    [
        "2022-09-21",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-09-22",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-09-23",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-09-24",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-09-25",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-09-26",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-09-27",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-09-28",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-09-29",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-09-30",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-01",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-02",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-03",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-04",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-05",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-06",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-07",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-08",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-09",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-10",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-11",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-12",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-13",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-14",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-15",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-16",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-17",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-18",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-19",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-20",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-21",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-22",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-23",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-24",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-25",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-26",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-27",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-28",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-29",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-30",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-10-31",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-01",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-02",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-03",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-04",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-05",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-06",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-07",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-08",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-09",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-10",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-11",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-12",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-13",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-14",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-15",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-16",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-17",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-18",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-19",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-20",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-21",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-22",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-23",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-24",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-25",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-26",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-27",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-28",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-29",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-11-30",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-01",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-02",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-03",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-04",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-05",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-06",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-07",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-08",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-09",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-10",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-11",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-12",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-13",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-14",
        0
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-15",
        45.22
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-16",
        45.22
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-17",
        45.22
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-18",
        45.22
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-19",
        45.22
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-20",
        45.22
    ],
    [
        "2022-12-21",
        45.22
    ]
],

                color: "#5f76e8c7",
            },
        ],
        //resize: true,
        credits: {
            enabled: false,
        },
    };
```

Comment: Hi @sokida, I am not sure what effect you want to achieve. If you want to show all of the labels, you can set `labels.step` to 1. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t397pw0L/

Comment: hi @ppotaczek i don't want to show all the label , i want a date range label for example if i have : ["2022-09-21",
    "2022-09-22",
    "2022-09-23",
    "2022-09-24",
    "2022-09-25",
    "2022-09-26",
    "2022-09-27",
    "2022-09-28",
    "2022-09-29",
    "2022-09-30"] i want to show for example just 3 dates in xaxis

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Please check the `data-grouping` feature from Highstock which can be useful in your case https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping With basic Highcharts, you can try to use the `labels.formatter` function to build connected label text. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8s6uwn5a/

Comment: It's works thank u so much can you add this like a response so can help other people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `data-grouping` feature from Highstock which can be useful in your case: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping

With basic Highcharts, you can try to use the `labels.formatter` function to build connected label text. For example:

```
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    tickInterval: 15,
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        const tickInterval = this.axis.tickInterval;

        if (!this.isFirst) {
          return this.value + ' - ' + this.axis.names[this.pos - tickInterval];
        }

        return this.value;
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8s6uwn5a/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter